# How to pass the ng-model into a function instead of ng-model's value?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I want to create a single function that will be used for total project.

It will work based on the ng-model passed into it.

For ex:-

```
 $scope.checkBoxValueChanged=function(model) {
   if($scope.model=="AA") {
     $scope.model="BB";
   }
   else {
     $scope.model="BB";
   }
  };
});
```

If i have the passed model's value as "AA" then i need to assign the passed model's value as "BB"

But what i am getting is the model value instead of model name.

Can anyone tell me how to get the model instead of model value.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: @camden_kid I must not hard code the ng-model into the function, the function will work for whatever the model it is passed into it.

Comment: Can you show an example of where this function might be called from including how you're currently passing its parameter?

Comment: @camden_kid please see the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/BfZQQe?p=preview

Comment: @MarcKline please see the plunker plnkr.co/edit/BfZQQe?p=preview

Comment: See ExpertSystem's answer re: how you need to pass a string and then use [] inside function. You could duplicate the model name in your function call (ie manually type it again). Or, maybe you can write an attribute directive that grabs it from the `ng-model` attribute of your element and then calls your function with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass the property name (what you refer to as "model") as a string parameter.
Then you can access it using the `object[key]` syntax.

```
$scope.checkBoxValueChanged = function(propName) {
    if($scope[propName] === 'AA') {
        $scope[propName] = 'BB';
    } else {
        $scope[propName] = 'AA';
    }
};
```

---

BTW, in JS, `scope.model` is equivalent to `scope['model']`, so the dot syntax won't work as you want it to.

Comment: @ExperySystem i have a model $scope.a={i:'aaa'}. I tried displaying the alert using the code, alert($scope['a.i']);. I am getting the alert message with nothing in the box. Can you tell me where i went wrong

Comment: Like I wrote: `$scope['a.i']` will try to access a property named `a.i`. You want to access a property named `i` of the object stored in a property named `a` of `$scope`. So: `$scope['a']['i']`.

Comment: Nice idea, but when i pass the model name as string (say checkBoxValueChanged(a,i))into a method, then how can i pass the argument into the code $scope['a']['i'], is it like $scope[arg1][arg2]

Comment: It is kind of unclear what you are trying to do. Why don't post some example (with exact input and expected output) ?